# Как построить столбчатую диаграмму с разными цветами в каждом элементе

Tags: python, pandas, list, matplotlib, диаграммы

Есть следующий список:

```
a_list = [['CCCCC', 519], ['GGGGG', 724], ['DDDDD', 549], ['AAAAA', 500], ['FFFFF', 599], ['BBBBB', 510], ['EEEEE', 599]]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на столбчатой диаграмме для каждого значения был определённый цвет, который я сам смогу выбрать в самом коде.

Я написал небольшой код, но я незнаю, что делать с цветом

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(pd.DataFrame(sorted(a_list, key=lambda x: x[1]), columns=["Города", "Кол-во"])
  .set_index("Города")
  .plot.barh(grid=False, figsize=(10,8), color=('#678cff')))
plt.title("Кол-во города")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(a_list, key=lambda x: x[1]), columns=["Города", "Кол-во"])
df["color"] = ["red", "black", "blue", "yellow", "green", "magenta", "gold"]

df.set_index("Города")["Кол-во"].plot.barh(grid=True, color=df["color"])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что делать, если у меня будет больше значений цвета, или наоборот список будет больше?
У выходит ошибка:

ValueError: Length of values (50) does not match length of index (37)

50 - кол-во цветов.
37 - кол-во объектов в списке.

Как я могу зараннее определить кол-во элементов списка, если оно может увеличиваться или наоборот, чтобы сразу определить, сколько нужно мне цветов сделать?

Comment: Число цветов должно соответствовать числу строк во фрейме. В качестве альтернативного варианта можно вместо цветов задать название `colormap` -  в этом случае matplotlib будет автоматически выбирать цвета из указанной палитры

Comment: ```
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(a_list, key=lambda x: x[1]), columns=["Города", "Кол-во"])
cmap = cm.get_cmap('hsv')
df.set_index("Города")['Кол-во'].plot.barh(grid=False, figsize=(10,8), cmap=cmap)
```
Я использовал colormap, но у меня почему то выбирается только 1-ый из этого списка цветов - красный (Cyclic colormaps)
Я не уверен, но думаю, что цвета могут так повторяться и в итоге сливаться на диаграмме.